# How to get my prost_types::DescriptorProto for my message from .proto file?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, grpc, tonic, prost

How to get my prost_types::DescriptorProto for my message from .proto file?

I have written a rust program to invoke google bigquery storage write API via grpc w/ protobuf by gcloud-sdk "google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1".

https://github.com/abdolence/gcloud-sdk-rs

2023-02-17T08:16:04.492220Z DEBUG gcloud_sdk::middleware: OK: /google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWrite/AppendRows took 262ms (incl. token gen: 0ms) Error: Status { code: InvalidArgument, message: "Invalid proto schema: BqMessage.proto: my.proto: \"my.proto\" is not a valid identifier. Entity: projects/steam-sequencer-xxxxxx/datasets/my_dataset/tables/test_table/streams/_default", source: None }

There is an argument puzzling me particularly!

pub struct ProtoSchema {     pub proto_descriptor: Option<DescriptorProto>, }

ProtoSchema describes the schema of the serialized protocol buffer data rows.

It's a "prost_types::DescriptorProto" indeed.

In many languages, it is generated/supported by the languages/package out-of-the-box.

Because I am a newbie for Rust, Prost & Grpc, does any one know how to get the DescriptorProto struct from my proto file via prost / tonic crate ?

Thank you very much!

```
   let x = DescriptorProto {
        name: Some(String::from("my.proto")),
        field: vec![],
        extension: vec![],
        nested_type: vec![],
        enum_type: vec![],
        extension_range: vec![],
        oneof_decl: vec![],
        options: None,
        reserved_range: vec![],
        reserved_name: vec![],
    };

    let proto_schema = ProtoSchema {
        proto_descriptor: Some(x),
    };

    let proto_data = ProtoData {
        writer_schema: Some(proto_schema),
        rows: Some(proto_rows),
    };
```